# Where do I put my map specific config for a Team Fortress 2 server?

Tags: team-fortress-2, server-administration

I've tried putting the map config in the following locations:

- `tf/cfg/cp_process_final.cfg`
- `tf/maps/cp_process_final.cfg`
- `tf/maps/cfg/cp_process_final.cfg`

I execute `rcon changelevel cp_process_final` and I still get the error message each time

```
'cp_process_final.cfg' not present; not executing.
```

I've heard that valve disabled map specific configs for TF2 after doing some reading.  Could anyone confirm if that is true? Because if the native doesn't work I'll have to find a plugin that does the job. Obviously I'd rather use the inbuilt function if available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving answer from comments:

---

`tf/cfg/cp_process_final.cfg` is the correct path.

However I tended to store configs in `tf/custom/map_configs/cfg/`. Since 2013, this will be treated like it was `tf/cfg` because of how the custom directory is treated.